# How large does a log file get after it updates every database table field?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, logfiles

My general question is, say you have a SQL Server 2005 database that's 20G in size and a log file that is empty. If you run a series of updates that touch each table and each row exactly once, will the log file grow to the same size as the database? Or will this depend on other factors?

I'm asking this question because of a database update I'm performing. I have a database used by some proprietary software. Updates are made to every table and every field. The software does not have a verbose output, just a checkbox for "not done"/"done". Because there's no descriptive output, I'm trying to figure out how to tell if it's close to the end.

So, is the log file likely to be the same size as the database when everything has been touched? Or does the log file contain different information that doesn't depend on the database size in this way?

Comment: What is your recovery model? Simple? Full? Bulk-logged. And apart from that, are you updating in batches of e.g. 1000 records or 'all at once'. You do not want to do 'all at once' with that amount of records..

Comment: Simple. The transaction is not committed until the end, so my understanding is that this is effectively the same size as "Full" until it's committed. Unfortunately (for me) it's automated in the software so I don't have control over that part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule of thumb the size of log generated for any update is about 1.5x the size of the update. So if you update 20Gb worth of data, you generate 30Gb worth of log.

But there are some things to consider:

1. Size of log generated does not need necessarily translates to log file size. Under SIMPLE recovery model the log file used can be automatically recycled as soon as the transaction commits (I'm omitting some details for brevity) so 30gb log size can fit in a 1gb file, by continuously recycling the used log. Under FULL and BULK recovery model the log gets similarly recycled when a database log backup is performed. So if you *don't* update everything in one transaction, your log should recycle and not grow.
2. Some operations can be minimally logged. TRUNCATE, INSERT BULK being the typical examples. Minimal logging takes a tiny fraction of normal logging.

Right now you should be looking at the log percent used (`DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)`) and also monitor if any [log growth events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191263.aspx) are occurring.

Comment: This is some great insight, that helps me get a grasp of the situation quite a bit better. Thank you for the reference link.

Comment: This link is for SQL 2000, but is still mostly accurate and very, very detailed: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966500.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer your looking for, but I think it's unlikely to relate to the size of the database in any meaningful way. Just wait it out. :)